# Django REST Framework unable to send multiple data

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send multiple JSON data in a single POST as a list like -

```
[
 {
    "name": "data",
 },
 {
    "name": "data",
 }
]
```

but getting the following error.

```
{
"non_field_errors": [
    "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
]
}
```

Here are my codes -

Serializers.py

```
class my_serializer_name(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = my_model
    fields = '__all__'

def validate(self, data):
    #Performing validation
    ......
    ......
```

viewsets.py

```
class my_viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = models.my_model.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.my_serializer
http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

def list(self, request):
    # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = serializers.my_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

router.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('name' , my_viewset)
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to override post method to specify serializer : instead of default serializer, use `many=True`

```
class my_viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.my_model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.my_serializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def post(self, request):
        serialized = my_serializer_name(data=request.data, many=True)
        serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serialized.save()
```

Comment: If you are referring to put this methond in the views.py, I did not write anything for the REST framework on views.py. I passed the URL as path('api/' , include(router.urls)) on the urls.py and the router and other files are mentioned on the question. Is there any alternative to this appoarch?

Comment: Since what you ask if a POST behaviour different from drf's provided specification, it makes sense to override the method. You would have to put this as a method of your my_viewset class, in `viewsets.py` rather than in `views.py`

Comment: I added the create method on the viewsets.py and it is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Create method on the viewsets.py file and it seems to be working fine.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data,list))
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```